# Existence of inverse element of an algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

My professor defined an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ as a vector space equipped with a map $\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ satisfying:
$$a(b+c) = ab + ac \quad a(bc) = (ab)c \quad a(kb) = k(ab)$$
for every $a,b,c \in \mathcal{A}$ and $k \in \mathbb{K}$. Let us assume that this algebra has a unit $1$, so that $a1 = 1a = a$ for every $a \in \mathcal{A}$.

I am supposed to prove some properties of the multiplication on an algebra. Example: $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$. To do it, I simply wrote:
$$(ab)^{-1}(ab) = 1 = b^{-1}a^{-1}ab $$
and multiplied first both sides on the right by $b^{-1}$ and then both sides on the right by $a^{-1}$. However, I noticed that I am postulating the existence of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, which is not assumed in the definition of an algebra, so my reasoning might not be correct. Is there any existence theorem, say, that every element has an inverse or something like this?

Comment: It is possible for $ab$ to have an inverse, yet for neither $a$ nor $b$ to have inverses.

Comment: Your professor should have stated more clearly that you must **assume** $a$ and $b$ have inverses. Inverses are **not** guaranteed in an algebra with a unit.

Comment: The result also holds if we assume $\mathcal{A}$ is finite dimensional. I've added this argument to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your qualms are justified. It is possible for $ab$ to have an inverse, but for neither $a$ nor $b$ to have an inverse.

To see an example of this phenomenon, let $V$ be the real vector space of all real sequences with its usual addition and scalar multiplication making it a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the vector space of all linear operators $T\colon V\to V$. Define "multiplication"  in $\mathcal{A}$ by composition of functions. Then we have the desired properties: $U\circ (R+S) = U\circ R + U\circ S$, $U\circ(R\circ S) = (U\circ R)\circ S$, and $k(U\circ R) = (kU)\circ R = U\circ(kR)$ for any linear operators $U,R,S\colon V\to V$ and scalar $k\in\mathbb{R}$. The algebra has a unit, the identity map $I_{V}$.

Now let $b\colon V\to V$ be the "right shift" operator and $a\colon V\to V$ be the "left shift" operator:
$$\begin{align*}
b(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) &= (0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\\
a(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) &= (a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots)
\end{align*}$$
Then clearly $ab=\mathrm{id}_V$, so $ab=1$ is invertible.

However, $b$ is not surjective, so it does not have a two-sided inverse; and $a$ is not injective, so it does not have a two-sided inverse. Thus, even though $(ab)^{-1}$ exists, neither $a^{-1}$ nor $b^{-1}$ do, so the expression $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is incoherent.

What *is* true is that if $a$ and $b$ are invertible, **then** we can conclude that $ab$ is invertible and that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, using the argument you give, *after* proving that an invertible element has a unique inverse.

Alternatively, the result also holds if $\mathcal{A}$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{K}$.

Indeed, suppose that this is the case. Then for each $a\in \mathcal{A}$, the map $m_a\colon \mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$ given by $m_a(x) = ax$ is a linear transformation: for $a(x+y) = ax+ay$ and $a(kx) = k(ax)$ for all scalars $k$.

Since $m_{a}\circ m_b = m_{ab}$, if $ab$ is invertible, that means that $m_{ab}$ is invertible, with inverse $m_{(ab)^{-1}}$. But $m_{ab}=m_{a}\circ m_{b}$. That means that $m_a$ is surjective and $m_b$ is injective. Because we are also assuming that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite dimensional, that means that $m_a$ and $m_b$ are both bijective functions. In particular, there exists $x\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $m_a(x) = 1$, so $ax=1$; that is, $a$ has a right inverse. Then $m_x$ has a left inverse, hence is bijective, so $m_x = (m_a)^{-1}$. This means that $m_{xa} = m_{1}$, so $xa = m_{xa}(1) = m_1(1) = 1$; thus, $xa=ax=1$, so $a$ is invertible, Once you know that $ab$ and $a$ are invertible, it follows that $b$ is also invertible, or you can repeat the argument with $m_b$.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I am still confused about the fact that I used $(ab)^{-1}ab = 1$. I used this property because of the definition of inverse, but if I am assuming $a$ and $b$ is invertible, shouldn't I prove that $ab$ has an inverse before using $(ab)^{-1}ab = 1$? But then, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: @InMathweTrust If $a$ and $b$ are invertible, then $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab) = 1$ and $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=1$, so $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is an inverse of $ab$, and in particular $ab$ is invertible with inverse $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.