# Does x and y have an inverse if xy has it.

Tags: ring-theory

We have a non-commutative ring but without divisors of zero. If $xy(xy)^{-1}=1$ (unit) do $x$ and $y$ also have an inverse so that $xx^{-1}=1$ and $yy^{-1}=1$?

My english is not very good, hope you understand the questions.

Comment: In a noncommutative ring, it is possible for $xy$ to have inverses but for neither $x$ nor $y$ to have inverses. E.g., [this linear algebra example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4593171/742).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Existence of inverse element of an algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593164/existence-of-inverse-element-of-an-algebra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the assumption that your ring has no nonzero zero divisors, it is indeed possible for a product to be invertible but neither factor be invertible. [A classical example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4593171/742) is the ring of endomorphisms of an infinite dimensional vector space.

But if you assume that the ring has no nonzero zero divisors, then if $xy$ is invertible then so are $x$ and $y$. Indeed, suppose that $r$ is an inverse for $xy$, so that $rxy = xyr = 1$. Then $yr$ is a right inverse for $x$, that is, $x(yr)=1$.

Now, $xyrx = (xyr)x = x$, so $0 = xyrx -x = x(yrx - 1)$. Therefore, since we are assuming that $R$ has no nonzero zero divisors, either $x=0$, which is impossible (since then $x(yr)=1$ wouldn't hold) or $yrx-1=0$. Thus, $yrx = 1$. Hence we have $x(yr)=(yr)x = 1$, so $yr=x^{-1}$. Once we have that $x$ and $xy$ both have inverses, it follows that $y$ has an inverse, since $y = x^{-1}(xy)$ is the product of two invertible elements.